# Cake PHP JS Helper

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I am learning cakephp 2.0 and trying to work on Ajax. I have successfully created a form which is working with ajax. Now I need to work on links. What I want to do is to fadein a div by clicking on a link.

```
  <?php $this->Js->get('#Edit-link')->event('click',$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'));?>
```

This code is not working and generating below javascript

```
    $("#sending").bind("click", function (event) {$("#sending").fadeIn();
return false;});
$("#sending").bind("click", function (event) {$("#sending").fadeIn();
return false;});
$("#sending").bind("click", function (event) {$("#sending").fadeIn();
return false;});
$("#sending").bind("click", function (event) {$("#sending").fadeIn();
return false;});
```

Answer (score 1):

All the code you've posted appears to be correct. The JsHelper should output the jQuery script you've included, except for the fact that it's printed 4 times, which is probably due to the second call to `$this->Js->get()` inside the first function.

What's not working exactly? Is the jQuery library correctly loaded [as per the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html)?

This script expects a link with the id `#sending` to be present. It also doesn't prevent the normal behaviour of a link to execute (following the url in the `href` attribute), which reloads the page and halts any JavaScript effects or actions to properly take place. Normally you would include `event.preventDefault()` inside a jQuery function to prevent this ([see the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)). Could you provide the complete code for your view?

Also, it might be more feasible to write this type of script directly in the jQuery syntax, doing it the Cake way adds more abstraction in this case, which might be unnecessary for small projects.

Comment: Actually I want it to generate this JS  $("#Edit-link").bind("click", function (event) {$("#sending").fadeIn();
return false;}); but you see the generated JavaScript above

Comment: If I run your code with the addition of `false` as the third parameter of `$this->Js->get('#Edit-link')->event()` I get the script you want. Without the addition it doesn't even print the line, nor does it do this four consecutive times. Are you sure it isn't wrapped in a loop somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean   <?php $this->Js->get('#Edit-link')->event('click',$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),false);?> I was in a foreach loop but I have removed it from there. But putting 'false' its not generating javascript. I have another call of Js just above it <?php echo $this->Js->link('Show all post', 'http://localhost/practice/cakephp/posts/ajaxcall', array(
    'update' => '#content2',
    'htmlAttributes' => array('other' => 'value')
));?>. Its working fine.